# How to make a categorical legend?

Tags: r, mapping

- Step 1: Stacking of tiff map
- Step 2: Plot map
- Step 3: Make legend categorical instead of continuous
- Step 4: Failed Attempt and Error message

```
    y1= stack(s1)
    names(y1)
    y1=na.omit(as.data.frame(y1,xy=TRUE)) 
    colnames(y1) <- c("X","Y","B2","B3","B4","B5","B6","B7",
                      "B8","B8A","B11","B12","NDVI","NDWI","MMRI","IRECI","MASI","VV","VH")
    
    AGCmap_1= predict(lm.fit,y1) # Predict based on lm.fit model and tiff data y 
    AGCmap_1= AGCmap_1*5 #UPSCALE to 1ha 
    AGCmap1= cbind(y1[,1:2],AGCmap_1)
    AGCmap1<-rasterFromXYZ(AGCmap1) 
    # Set Z-lim based on to MAX value 
    plot(AGCmap1,zlim=c(0,80))
```

[image: Carbon map]

```
library(classInt)
breaks_qt <- classIntervals(c(min(AGCmap_1) - .00001, AGCmap_1), n = 5, style = "quantile")
```

[image]

```
AGCmap_1 <- mutate(AGCmap_1, AGCmap_1= cut(AGCmap_1, breaks_qt$brks))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Hi I hope this help you, follow steps, also you can reproducible it with the next data in this [link](https://github.com/barja8/ExampleTmap)**

```
library(raster)
library(tmap)
library(cptcity)
library(tidyverse)

# reading a raster ---------------------------------------
dem <- raster('../Data/DEM.gpkg')

# definition some class for raster -----------------------
class <- c( -Inf, 3000 , 1,
            3000, 3500 , 2,
            3500, 4000 , 3,
            4000, Inf  , 4)
class %>%
  matrix(ncol = 3,byrow = T) -> m_class

dem %>% 
  reclassify(m_class) %>% 
  as.factor() -> r_class

levels(r_class)[[1]]$names <- c('very low','low',
                                'medium','high')

# Map with rater layer ------------------------------------
r_class %>% 
tm_shape() + 
  tm_raster(palette = cpt(pal = 'grass_bcyr',
                          n = 4),
            legend.hist = TRUE) +
  tm_layout(frame = FALSE,
            legend.outside = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: You can plot raster objects by defined ranges using `breaks` or `cuts` depending on plot method, without reclassifying the data. For large rasters, reclassification is IO intensive.

Comment: @Jeffrey Evans Yes indeed.I fail to code the correct cut line though.